# How to organise dynamic number of uitableview as swiping pages in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uikit

There is a dynamic set of data i have to organise as set of swiped tables. Now I'm using UIPageViewController for this task, but it has some problems with dynamically uploaded data from net - if we swiping pages too fast, we can overtake data loading and program can crashes. Now, to solve this problems, i'm uploading data in advance of 5 pages, but i think it's bad solution and i hope there is a right solving for this task.
I found another idea - using UICollectionView for this task, but i'm not sure, that i can use tables as UICollectionViewCell in this method and i'm not sure, that this decision is correct. 
What can you recommend in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my approach to such case

- first I would have my ViewController containing the collectionView as below -make sure to add your own constraints however you would like-

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

// MARK: Lifecycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupCollectionView()
    }

// MARK: Private Methods
    private func setupCollectionView(){
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.separatorStyle = .none
        collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: /* Your cell NibName */, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: /* Your cell Id*/)
        collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true
    }

// MARK: UICollectionView Methods
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return zekr?.subNodes?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = zekrCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: /* Your cell Id */, for: indexPath) as! /* Your cell Type */
        cell.cellData = /* your list that corresponds with the list that table will take */
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // this is to make each cell fill the whole page
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    }


}
```

- then you will add tableview inside each collectionViewCell and for sure to fulfill the delegate and datasource for the tableView inside the collectionViewCell as below

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    // MARK: IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var pageTable: UITableView!

    var cellData: [/*Your List*/]?

    // MARK: Properties
    var cellData: /*Your List*/?{
        didSet{
            if let value = cellData {
                /* reload your table */
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: Life Cycle Methods
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupPageTable()
    }

    private func setupPageTable(){
        pageTable.delegate = self
        pageTable.dataSource = self
        pageTable.register(UINib(nibName: /* TableView Cell NibName */, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: /* CellId */)
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDelegate
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellData?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: /* CellId */) as! /* Cell Type */
        cell.cellDataModel = cellData?[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = cellData?[indexPath.row]
        return cell.contentView.frame.size.height
    }

}
```

- and finally your tableViewCell will remain as the same however you done it initially passing to it the cellDataModel
- in case the horizontal scrolling did't work for the collectionView you can google a solution depending on your swift version
- the result you will be having collectionView on your home or whatever VC you are on with horizontal scrolling each cell containing tableView with it's cells with vertical scrolling acting as viewPager in android